# Laravel query with date not working on the server but working good on localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel

`->whereBetween('date', array( '2015-3-01', '2015-3-31' ))` not working on the server but working good on the localhost, I have the same MySQL data on both.

I have tested to execute a query `(date between '2015-3-01' and '2015-3-31')` direct on phpMyadmin (server and localhost) and it work fine,

Comment: In what way isn't it working? Does it error? Does it return incorrect results? Does it return no results?

Comment: Enable debug logging in config/database.php to write the actual query that is being executed to the log.... or try passing DateTime/Carbon objects as your dates instead of strings

Comment: it return no results. I tested with select subtotal from `invoices` where `user_id` = '4' and `status` = 'paid' and `date` between '2015-3-01' and '2015-3-31' on phpMyadmin and it return true value but from the laravel controller DB::select("select subtotal from `invoices` where `user_id` = '4' and `status` = 'paid' and `date` between '2015-3-01' and '2015-3-31'"); return nothing.<br> no error on the debug

Comment: Have you tried enabling debug in config/database.php to see what query is actually being executed?

Comment: yes, the query is right but no results on the website but the same query on the database return the true value

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem , istead for ('2015-3-01' and '2015-3-31') should use ('2015-03-01' and '2015-03-31'). strange but working. thx for all of you!